# Constant in Hibernate Mapping Files

Tags: hibernate

I would like to add a value object to a mapped class where one column is fixed depending of the class that contains the component. How can I do something like this?

```
<component name="aComponent">
  <property name="abc" column="cde"/>
  <property name="xyz" value="FIXED"/>
</component>
```

Unfortunatly, the value attribute does not exist. Is there another way to apply a constant value to property?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a formula, e.g.

```
<property name="xyz" formula="1" type="big_decimal"/>
```

From Java Persistence with Hibernate, ch. 4.4.1:

> The given SQL formula is evaluated every time the entity is retrieved from the
>   database (and not at any other time, so the result may be outdated if other
>   properties are modified). The property doesn’t have a column attribute (or subelement)
>   and never appears in an SQL `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, only in `SELECT`s. Formulas
>   may refer to columns of the database table, they can call SQL functions,
>   and they may even include SQL subselects. The SQL expression is passed to the
>   underlying database as is; this is a good chance to bind your mapping file to a
>   particular database product, if you aren’t careful and rely on vendor-specific
>   operators or keywords.